# How add attibute with value in object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Here is input that i gave

```
{
header: "dc_header.png"
icon: "dc_icon.png"
id: "DCA"
latitude: 38.89511
longitude: -77.03637
name: "Washington DC"
}
```

and i want to add distance in it like

```
{
header: "dc_header.png"
icon: "dc_icon.png"
id: "DCA"
latitude: 38.89511
longitude: -77.03637
name: "Washington DC"
**distance: 10**
}
```

How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new key-value pair to an object this way:

```
objectName.distance = 10
```

You should change 'objectName' to the name of your object.

Answer (score 0):

If this is truly React question then potentially modifying the state is a bad idea. I propose that you spread the original object over a new object and add the additional property at the end.

```js
const obj = {
  header: "dc_header.png",
  icon: "dc_icon.png",
  id: "DCA",
  latitude: 38.89511,
  longitude: -77.03637,
  name: "Washington DC"
};

const modifiedObj = {
  ...obj,
  distance: 10
};

console.log(modifiedObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you are mapping objects, you can do this similarly:

```js
const distances = [ 10 ];

const objs = [{
  header: "dc_header.png",
  icon: "dc_icon.png",
  id: "DCA",
  latitude: 38.89511,
  longitude: -77.03637,
  name: "Washington DC"
}];

const modifiedObjs = objs.map((obj, index) => ({
  ...obj,
  distance: distances[index]
}));

console.log(modifiedObjs);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```